# Media files not appearing on a react site

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-location

I am serving a react application with Nginx. I need my application to be hosted on <my_domain>/505. I am attaching the location section for your reference. The issue is that all the APIs are getting through, but nothing is displaying in the site. Also, I found that there is no media file showing up on the page sources section which is actually present in the same location as CSS and js.

I would like to know what is the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance for your time – if I’ve missed out anything, over-or under-emphasised a specific point let me know in the comments.

```
    location ^~ /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/8357/static/;
    }

    location ^~ /media/ {
       autoindex on;
       alias /usr/share/nginx/html/8357/static/media/;
    }

    location /505 {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
```